# Cannot Submit 1st Expo React Native Android app to Google Play Store

Tags: android, react-native, file-upload, expo, submission

I am sure there is an easy answer but I cannot find it in the documentation.

I am trying to submit my first Expo React Native Android app to the Google Play Store. You cannot use eas submit on the first submission.

When I upload my app  for internal testing I get the following error:

Your APK or Android App Bundle's package name must be in the following format "com.example.myapp". It may contain letters (a-z), numbers, and underscores (_). It must start with a lowercase character. It must be 150 characters or fewer.

Is the package name the same as the file name? My filename is sermon.engagement.wintonbury.aab. Where is the package name defined?

Thanks - sorry if I am missing something obvious!

Answer (score 1):

Inside `app.json`file find or add `package:com.yourdomain.appname` and use a unique domain name.

https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/config/app/#package
https://developers.cafebazaar.ir/en/guidelines/build-app/package-name